# Do I have to activate a parent theme when I activate its sub theme?

Tags: 7, theming

A sub theme relies on its parent. Does that mean I always have to activate both of them?

Comment: I recently created a child theme of Radix but got a WSOD. The dblog revealed that Radix wasn't enabled, so there must be some functionality that fails when it's disabled, although Drupal is able to detect the need for such functionality even though I hadn't made any code changes to the child theme at this point, so although the accepted answer is "No", I'm guessing it depends on the parent theme's behavior.

Comment: Are you on D7 as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it doesn't. As long as the base theme is present, that's OK.

As an example, if you test the [Sky](http://www.drupal.org/project.sky) theme on [Simplytest.me](http://simplytest.me) and go to the *admin/appearance* page, you'll see that Sky is enabled, but the base theme ([AdaptiveTheme](https://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme)) is not.

Comment: Keeping in mind that if you don't have the base theme enabled you will not receive notification updates if there are any for it.

Comment: @NigelWaters This is a very good point! Thanks for that, I'd never even thought about that before *hangs head in shame*

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8, the base theme is automatically enabled.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2232651

> When a sub-theme is installed, then its base theme(s) are installed,
>   too.